# Private CocoaPods – [!] Unable to add a source with url `` named `-1`

Tags: swift, cocoapods

I just tried creating a private Pod by following [this tutorial on TutsPlus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/managing-private-pods-with-cocoapods--cms-25137). Everything works fine, until I try doing `pod repo push REPO_NAME SPEC_NAME.podspec`, where I get the following error:

```
Validating spec
Cloning spec repo `-1` from ``
[!] Unable to add a source with url `` named `-1`.
You can try adding it manually in `~/.cocoapods/repos` or via `pod repo add`.
```

I used `pod repo push MFPods ~/Desktop/MFReusable/BlinkingLabel/BlinkingLabel.podspec` for trying to add it, but without luck.

*Note: `BlinkingLabel.podspec` has passed validation, and MFPods has been added to `~/.cocoapods/repos`. Only the pod's spec is missing...*

Any idea as to why I'm getting this output? Thanks.

Comment: Hi, did you find the solution?

Comment: Hi, could you show us the content of `~/Desktop/MFReusable/BlinkingLabel/BlinkingLabel.podspec` ?

Comment: Change push to  add?

Answer (score 2):

I just had the same problem.
Through a lot of trial and error, I found out that my Xcode-developer path was not set correctly anymore.
After I fixed that using `sudo xcode-select --switch path/to/the/Xcode/you/use`, the crazy error did not occur anymore.

Comment: I used `Xcodes` to install Xcode 14 but renamed Xcode-14.0.app to just Xcode.app and got this error and this resolved the issue for me.

Answer (score 2):

I had this same problem and tried  Tibrogargan's answer like this:

```
pod repo push --sources=https://my.private.repo/PodSpecs MYSpecs MyLib.podspec
```

then I got other error like:

```
Validating spec
 -> MyLib (0.1.0)
    - ERROR | [iOS] unknown: Encountered an unknown error (Unable to find a specification for `AFNetworking` depended upon by `MyLib/Base`) during validation.
```

and I tried this:

```
pod repo push --sources=https://my.private.repo/PodSpecs,https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs MYSpecs MyLib.podspec
```

finally my problem solved.

Answer (score 0):

I've been having the same issue and solved it by adding the URL of my podspec repo with the `--sources` argument for `pod repo push`.  Try something more like this:

```
pod repo push --sources=https://your.private.repo/PodSpecs MFPods ~/Desktop/MFReusable/BlinkingLabel/BlinkingLabel.podspec
```